# Error: Invalid value for argument 4. Property 'method': Unexpected property

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to change the request method (to make a POST request) of a request made by the user but I am getting this error:

`Error in event handler for webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders/1: Error: Invalid value for argument 4. Property 'method': Unexpected property.`

My code is this:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    return {method: "POST"};
}, { 
    urls: ["<all_urls>"]
}, ["blocking", "requestHeaders"]);
```

Am I missing something? I searched a lot but I can't find anything to change the request method with `webRequest`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the HTTP method is not immediately supported through the extension API. There are several ways to get the desired result. In the answer below, I'll only explain how to do this for requests of type `sub_frame` and `main_frame`, because that is probably what you wanted (POST for types such as `image` or `stylesheet` don't really make sense).

You can either modify the requestor such that it initiates a POST request instead of a GET request via a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). E.g. by locating the `<form>` and setting `action` to `"POST"`.

A general method that works is to intercept a request and redirect to an extension page of yours that in turn submits a form to the desired destination. **Do not forget to add the page to [`web_accessible_resources`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources)**. You can pass parameters to the frame by URL (query string or reference fragment), or store parameters in a dictionary in the background page and use the [extension messaging API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) for communication.
Example (using a query string for passing the URL):

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {
    var url = chrome.runtime.getURL('redirector.html') +
            '?' + encodeURIComponent(details.url)
    return {
        redirectUrl: url
    };
}, { 
    types: ['main_frame', 'sub_frame'],
    urls: ['*://example.com/*']
}, ['blocking']);
```

`redirector.html` (add this page to [`web_accessible_resources`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources)!):

```
<form method="POST" id="form"></form>
<script src="redirector.js"></script>
```

`redirector.js` could contain (note: validation of parameters is left as an exercise to the reader):

```
var form = document.forms['form'];

// URL is passed via the parameters
// "chrome-extension://[extensionid]/redirector.html?http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F
//                                                  ^
//                                                  becomes http://example.com
form.action = decodeURIComponent(location.search.slice(1));

// Example: Append extra form data
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'text'; // Default
input.value = 'extra data';
form.appendChild(input);

form.submit();
```

This is a very simple example. If you want to pass more data to the page, choose an appropriate serialization of the parameters (e.g. JSON or `&param=value`). Read the documentation for more information about (dynamically generated) forms: [`<form>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Form) and [`HTMLFormElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Really helped, but what I want it to change the request when the user goes to a page. For example I type `www.google.com` in a new tab and that makes a GET request, but I want it to be a POST request, for example. Is that possible?

Comment: @PabloMatíasGomez Yes, that is possible. I've updated my answer with an example of adding extra form data.

Comment: That's great ! I could do this but I have a problem, it is making an endless loop because the submit of the form makes the onBeforeRequest execute for the new request, how can I add a flag so that I can avoid when the request is made from my form?

Comment: I just figured it out adding a hidden and then checking in the requestBody. Thanks !!

Comment: Do you happen to know any way to do this with every method? form tags only support GET/POST methods :(

Comment: @PabloMatíasGomez Use `XMLHttpRequest` with the `FormData` API, see e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: @RobW, But why is the error message saying  `Invalid value for argument 4` when [the callback itself](http://archive.is/c5KAG#selection-6069.0-6069.8) only asks for one argument? Shouldn't it have been saying `Invalid value for argument 1`?